# Raspberry Pi 2 B and Kinect V2

Tags: kinect, openkinect, kinect-interaction

Is there anybody who can confirm it is possible to extract depth/RGB images from [Kinect V2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/purchase/) + [Kinect Adapter for Windows](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Kinect-Adapter-for-Windows/productID.308803600) on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?

As far as I know, Raspberry Pi 2 Model B has USB 3.0 which is a requirement for Kinect V2. I would like to know if anyone had success in RGB, IR and depth image transfer from Kinect V2 using [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2) or any other similar way.

Furthermore, anyone knows any hardware similar to Raspberry Pi 2 (more expensive but still cheap) which supports Kinect V2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Raspberry Pi 2 [datasheet](http://www.adafruit.com/pdfs/raspberrypi2modelb.pdf), it only has USB 2.0 ports. So it won't work. :-(

The most basic hardware that works that I know of is the [NVIDIA Jetson TK1](https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-tk1). At $192 it's way more expensive then a Raspberry Pi, but cheaper than most other options. For more information on using libfreenect2 with the TK1, see [this HOWTO](https://github.com/xlz/libfreenect2/wiki/Jetson-TK1-HOWTO)